# Scala internal compiler error (possibly?)

Tags: scala

Code runs fine in scala repl, will not compile as part of a scala source code base. Seems like the compiler is throwing some kind of an internal error.

I have a List[(String,(Int,Int))] I want to convert to Map[String,List[(Int,Int)] so that I can search it faster. It is basically a set of buckets indexed by the String component of the map that I can then search over and over using maybe binary search, once I have zeroed in on a bucket. I am trying to build the Map structure from the List structure, using a foldLeft operation.

```
val tpls:List[(String,(Int,Int))] = sm.compressedSegmentList.
    map(_.split("|")).
    map(s => (s(1), s(2).toInt, s(3).toInt)).
    sortBy(_._1).
    map(s => (s._1 -> (s._2,s._3)))

val chrBuckets:Map[String,List[(Int,Int)]] = 
    tpls.
    foldLeft(Map().empty.asInstanceOf[String,List[(Int,Int)]])(
      (y,x) => { 
        if (!y.contains(x._1)) y ++ Map(x._1->List(x._2)) 
        else y ++ Map(x._1 -> (y(x._1):+x._2))
      }
    )
```

In the scala REPL, I can do the following:

```
scala> val l1 = List(("a",(1,2)),("a", (2,3)), ("a",(3,4)), ("b", (17,18)), ("b", (18,19)), ("c", (20,21)), ("d",(0,0)))

l1: List[(String, (Int, Int))] = List((a,(1,2)), (a,(2,3)), (a,(3,4)), (b,(17,18)), (b,(18,19)), (c,(20,21)), (d,(0,0)))

scala> l1.foldLeft(Map().empty.asInstanceOf[Map[String,List[(Int,Int)]]])((y,x) => if (!y.contains(x._1)) y ++ Map(x._1->List(x._2)) else y ++ Map(x._1 -> (y(x._1):+x._2)))

res88: Map[String,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(a -> List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4)), b -> List((17,18), (18,19)), c -> List((20,21)), d -> List((0,0)))
```

However, when I compile my project using "sbt compile", it fails to compile by throwing up, such as:

```
[error]   last tree to typer: Ident(scala)
[error]        tree position: line 26 of /usr/home/maketo/util/SegmentMatcher.scala
[error]             tree tpe: scala.type
[error]               symbol: final package scala
[error]    symbol definition: final package scala (a ModuleSymbol)
[error]       symbol package: <none>
[error]        symbol owners: package scala
[error]            call site: class SegmentMatcher in package util in package util
[error] 
[error] == Source file context for tree position ==
[error] 
[error]     23   // within the bucket we can do binary search on "segStart" and "segEnd" fields
[error]     24   // after we sort first by segStart and then segEnd
[error]     25   val chrBuckets:Map[String,List[(Int,Int)]] = tpls.
[error]     26     foldLeft(Map().empty.asInstanceOf[String,List[(Int,Int)]])((y,x) => { if (!y.contains(x._1)) y ++ Map(x._1->List(x._2)) else y ++ Map(x._1 -> (y(x._1):+x._2))})
[error]     27 
[error]     28   // take a segment and match it against a segmentation
[error]     29   // return segment ID or None
[error]     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.throwAssertionError(SymbolTable.scala:183)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1189)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1243)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5740)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typed1$60(Typers.scala:5142)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTypeSelectionQualifier$1(Typers.scala:5142)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedSelectOrSuperCall$1(Typers.scala:5150)
```

.. snipped for brevity, to this:

```
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
[error]   Context(SegmentMatcher.scala) {
[error]    owner       = value chrBuckets
[error]    tree        = Apply:tpls.foldLeft(Map().empty.asInstanceOf[String, List[scala.Tuple2[Int, 
[error]    scope       = 0 decls
[error]    contextMode = MacrosEnabled TypeConstructorAllowed
[error]    outer.owner = value chrBuckets
[error] }
[error]      while compiling: /usr/home/maketo/SegmentMatcher.scala
[error]         during phase: typer
[error]      library version: version 2.12.8
[error]     compiler version: version 2.12.8
```

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in compiler. Report it [here](https://github.com/scala/bug)

Comment: [https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11333](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11333)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's an internal compiler error. The following snippet crashes 2.12.5 - 2.12.8 and 2.13.0-M5:

```
Map().asInstanceOf[Int, List[(Int, Int)]]
```

---

Workaround (that's what you should have done anyway, compiler error or not):

```
Map.empty[Int, List[(Int, Int)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are looking to figure out whether the above was a compiler error, but, if you are looking for a workaround, see if one of these 2 snippets work for you.

```
// Initialize
val tpls: List[(String, (Int, Int))] = List(
  "foo" -> (1, 2),
  "bar" -> (3, 4),
  "foo" -> (5, 6)
)

// Option 1 
tpls.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// returns Map(foo -> List((1,2), (5,6)), bar -> List((3,4)))

// Option 2
val emptyMap = Map.empty[String, List[(Int,Int)]].withDefaultValue(List.empty[(Int, Int)])

tpls.foldLeft(emptyMap) { case (mapSoFar, (segmentName, interval)) =>      
  mapSoFar.updated(segmentName, interval::mapSoFar(segmentName))
}
// returns Map(foo -> List((5,6), (1,2)), bar -> List((3,4)))
```

The second result is in reverse order, but, I just wanted to note that for lists :: is significantly less expensive that :+ (in case you don't care about the order)

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote the code, more just to test/confirm it would work. Thank you, much better/prettier than mine :)